# apex:commandButton is rendering properly under apex:pageBlockButtons

Tags: visualforce, rerender, selectlist

I have defined a SelectList under pageBlockButtons. The problem is top part of SelectList is getting rendered properly [selecting Temporary from list opens another Selectlist as expected], but bottom part is not working.

**To replicate the issue:**

Try it in your Org; you would find a SelectList next to Test1 button (both on top part and lower part -- Pls see the screen shot).

*Lets test Using TOP part (Pls see the screen shot):* Select Temporary from the drop down box, immediately a new DropDown shows next to it. -- This is fine.

*Test Using Lower part (Pls see the screen shot):* Select Temporary from the drop down box, in this time new DropDown does not show. -- **This is NOT fine.**

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="Cntl_SelectListTest1">
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb2">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">                                
              <apex:commandButton value="Test1"/>
              <apex:selectList id="selected_list" value="{!dropdown1}" required="false" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="1" itemLabel="Permanent"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="2" itemLabel="Temporary"/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="frm" action="{!change}"/>
              </apex:selectList>
                &nbsp;    
              <apex:selectList id="dropdown2" required="false" value="{!dropdown2}" size="1" rendered="{!IF(options != null && options.size > 0, true, false)}">                
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}" />
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="frm" />
              </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>                                
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>        
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Cntl_SelectListTest1 {
    public String dropdown1{get; set;}
    public String dropdown2{get; set;}
    public List<SelectOption> options{get; set;}

    public void  change() {        
        if(dropdown1 == '1') {                    
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
        } else if(dropdown1 == '2') {                    
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('1','1 Month'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('3','3 Months'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('6','6 Months'));   
            options.add(new SelectOption('12','1 Year'));
        }
   }

}
```

[image]

Please help...

[image]

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: @TusharSharma: The lower selectList. If I select lower selectList, it does not work.

Comment: When you are saying lower this means `dropdown2`. Also I  don't find any action which you are performing. You are just printing a debug. So the method does not get called?

Comment: No! Lower means the highlighted section + Test1 button.  And top parts mean, the Test1 button + selectLists (not highlighted in the snap).

Comment: @TusharSharma:  If you copy-paste the code in your org and try out the same, you would find the top part is working absolutely fine.
And, I want the lower part to work similarly..

Comment: @TusharSharma: Added a new screenshot to clarify top/bottom part

Comment: @sfdcfox : Can you please help me on this?

Comment: I also don't get what you mean by "not working". The _dropdown2_ selectList has an actionSupport being fired by "onchange" event, but it calls the _change1()_ method of your controller, which only prints a debug statement, does not interfere in anything else such as displayed options of the dropdowns. What exactly do you want to happen and is not?

Comment: Ok! I removed change1() method, as it's a bit confusing here. I don't have anything to do with this method.

Let's try describing the problem:
If you try it in your Org, you would find a SelectList next to Test1 button (both on top part and lower part  -- Pls see the screen shot).

Lets test Using TOP part:
Select Temporary from the drop down box, immediately a new DropDown shows next to it. -- This is fine.

Test Using Lower part:
Select Temporary from the drop down box, in this time new DropDown does not show. -- This is NOT fine.

Please let me know if require more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few posts in Salesforce developer's forum about this issue: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098qWIAQ and https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097vZIAQ

I couldn't find any explication of why it happens at a quick look, but apparently the most common solution to achieve the desired behavior is to split the *pageBlockButtons* in two. Instead of:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="both"> 
  ....
</apex>pageBlockButtons>
```

You would have one *pageBlockButtons* section with *location="top"* and another one with *location="bottom"*. There are some examples in the links I posted if you need some extra help.

Comment: Thanks @Mauricio
I followed this approach only (split the pageBlockButtons in two).
I checked the links, but unfortunately it's not applicable to my case.

Comment: @Robi - If it is not applicable in your case why did you accept the answer.

Comment: @Eric: The links are not applicable to my issue. Otherwise; the suggestion provided by Mauricio was correct.

Comment: @Eric: But, if anyone provides more specific answer (with VF page + controller), I shall accept that...